# Update DataGrid after insert with procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I know this question was asked but I can't figure out why this action is so complex.
So I have a `Produs` table

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [IDProdus]
    ,[Denumire]
    ,[UM]
    ,[Pret]
    ,[IDFurnizor]
    ,[IDCategorie]
    ,[IDTipProdus]
    ,[OperatorAdaugare]
    ,[DataAdaugare]
    ,[OperatorModificare]
    ,[DataModificare]
FROM [Proiect].[dbo].[Produse]
```

This is my table's columns. I added via Data Sources GUI from Visual Studio a `DataSet` with the content of this table (no actual code wrote by me).

Now I have a procedure that will insert me a new row in this Table.

Here is the code:

```
private void dToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection-string-here");
    string Query = "spGE_getProduse_Edit"; // Stored procedure name.
    int Integer; 
    conn.Open();
    // Creating SqlCommand object
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(Query, conn );
    // Here we declaring command type as stored procedure:
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDProdus", 0);       
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Denumire ",
        denumireTextBox.Text.ToString());     
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UM ",
        uMTextBox.Text.ToString());
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pret ",
        Double.Parse(pretTextBox.Text));
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDFurnizor ",
        Int16.Parse(iDFurnizorTextBox.Text));
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDCategorie ",
        Int16.Parse(iDCategorieCombobox.SelectedValue.ToString()));
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDTipProdus ",
        Int16.Parse(iDTipProdusCombobox.SelectedValue.ToString()));
    com.Parameters.Add("@IDProdusScris", SqlDbType.BigInt);
    com.Parameters["@IDProdusScris"].Direction =
        ParameterDirection.Output;
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();   
    Integer =
        Int32.Parse(com.Parameters["@IDProdusScris"].Value.ToString());
}
```

Now after insert I want to update `myGrid` with the new record. I tried
`dataGridView1.Refresh();` and `dataGridView1.Update();`, with no result.

Is there a way to update the grid? It looks like a simple task for VS, but I couldn't find a simple solution.

What I saw only and read on MSDN looked like some very complex operations just for a simple refresh. (It was about getting the state of the row and insert the row if the state was Added).

So is there any simple way to do this, or I have to write a method that will refresh my `dataGridView` every time I want (I mean to re-query my table and rebuild the `dataSource`)

Comment: Yes You have to write a method

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

`dataGridView1.Refresh();` and `dataGridView1.Update();` will not fetch updated records from db.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can use stored procedures are pre-complied

```
Create Procedure Sp_getProducts
as
BEGIN
SELECT TOP 1000 [IDProdus]
      ,[Denumire]
      ,[UM]
      ,[Pret]
      ,[IDFurnizor]
      ,[IDCategorie]
      ,[IDTipProdus]
      ,[OperatorAdaugare]
      ,[DataAdaugare]
      ,[OperatorModificare]
      ,[DataModificare]
  FROM [Proiect].[dbo].[Produse]

END
```

Use this code which Uses [Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) Statements

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection-string-here"))
{
conn.Open();
using(SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("Sp_getProducts",conn))
{
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable ds = new DataTable();
da.Fill(ds);
gridView.DataSource = ds;
gridView.DataBind();
conn.Close(); 
}

}
```

Comment: Actually, it's a very common **myth** - but stored procedures in SQL Server ***are not*** precompiled or anything like that - see [Pre-Compiled Stored Procedures: Fact or Myth](http://www.scarydba.com/2009/09/30/pre-compiled-stored-procedures-fact-or-myth/) or other sources for details

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your datasource:

```
dataGridView1.DataSourcce = null;
dataGridView1.DataSource = [YOUR DATASET];
dataGridView1.Refresh();
dataGridView1.Update();
```